# AVAudioPlayer causing exceptions when run concurrently

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, audio, crash

Every once in a while, `AVAudioPlayer` crashes when I call its `play` method.

My app is a game, with background music and many sound effects. Originally, `AVAudioPlayer` was causing it to run very slowly. However, as it seems to be the simplest sound API to work with, (especially for a 2D game like mine) I simply decided to play the sounds concurrently using `dispatch_async`.

This resulted in a considerable improvement, with no noticeable performance toll taken on the main thread of the game. But it crashes the game. Every 5 or 10 minutes, while playing, an exception appears.

I don't understand why this is happening. Is something being released internally within the player before it can be run concurrently? Or is it something else altogether?

**EDIT:**

This is a snippet of code I use to play sounds when the player collects coins in game. I use 4 `AVAudioPlayers` so the sounds can overlap:

```
if([coinCollectPlayer isPlaying]){
                if([coinCollectPlayer2 isPlaying]){
                    if([coinCollectPlayer3 isPlaying]){
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
                            [coinCollectPlayer4 play];});
                    }
                    else dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
                        [coinCollectPlayer3 play];});
                }
                else dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
                    [coinCollectPlayer2 play];});
            }
            else
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){[coinCollectPlayer play];});
```

Comment: You're playing sounds with AVAudioPlayer on a background thread???? Could we see the code, please?

Comment: Could you show in more detail why you think AVAudioPlayer "was causing it to run very slowly"? You seem to be under a misapprehension.

Comment: @matt code snippet in edited question. It seems from other people's experiences, along with my own, that `AVAudioPlayer` has a reputation for being a relatively slow, high-latency API for audio playback, particularly in games, which I have seen for myself, hence the multithreading. However, I may be going completely on a tangent here, so feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I see immediately one thing that's wrong with it: you are _checking_ `isPlaying` on a different thread than you are saying `play`. That's a recipe for occasional disaster (exactly what you are experiencing).

Comment: He who lives by the thread must die by the thread: if you are going to speak to your player on a background thread sometimes, you must do it always.

Comment: @matt Thank you, that didn't even occur to me! Obviously I'm not well acquainted with concurrency-  how would I go about checking whether the `AVAudioPlayer` is playing on its thread?

Comment: Define your own queue and use it for _every_ line of code that touches any of the AVAudioPlayer objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're crashing occasionally is that this structure is unsound:

```
if([coinCollectPlayer isPlaying]){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) { 
        [coinCollectPlayer play];
    });
}
```

You are checking `isPlaying` on the main thread. So how do you know that between then and when you say `play` on a background thread, you haven't already said `play` on a background thread? You don't. Think of it like this:

```
if([coinCollectPlayer isPlaying]){
    // GREAT BIG HOLE HERE YOU CAN DRIVE A TRUCK THROUGH
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) { 
        [coinCollectPlayer play];
    });
}
```

You need to use a consistent thread for all communication with your audio players, and either you must use locking / synchronize to enforce coherency or you must use a serial queue (which `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` is not).

Having said all that, I think what you're doing is just wrong. I don't believe that AVAudioPlayer needs to or should be used on a background thread.

What I suggest you try is to use every AVAudioPlayer *once*. In other words, to play a sound, make an AVAudioPlayer, play a sound, and throw the whole thing away.

Comment: Very helpful. But why would using each `AVAudioPlayer` once and then throwing it out result in better performance? wouldn't there be more overhead in reinitializing a player every time a sound effect needs to be played?

Comment: The "overhead" in reusing your audio players and having to check `isPlaying` all the time is the problem already.